# Why NULL values are excluded while selecting values from table

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I have written one sql query to get all records but not specific.

My table has a `column3` of type `INT` and can have some null values also. But the following queries are ignoring the records those have NULL in `column3`.

Table1:

```
ID | Column1 | Column2 | Column3
1     xyz        xyz       200
2     xyz        xyz       201
3     xyz        xyz       NULL
4     xyz        xyz       NULL
5     xyz        xyz       201
```

SQL query:

```
SELECT 
    [ID], 
    [Column1], [Column2], [Column3] // (int, null)
FROM 
    [Table1] 
WHERE
    Column3 != 201
```

LINQ query:

```
from tb in _entities.Table1
where tb.Column3 != 201
```

Since two NULL cannot be equal i.e `NULL = NULL` is always False. Why the above queries are excluding the records with null values. Only first record is being returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [explicitly](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191504(v=sql.105).aspx) specify that you want NULL values:

```
from tb in _entities.Table1
where tb.Column3 == null || tb.Column3 != 201
```

> When null values are present in data, logical and comparison operators
> can potentially return a third result of UNKNOWN instead of just TRUE
> or FALSE. This need for three-valued logic is a source of many
> application errors.
>
> Transact-SQL also offers an extension for null processing. If the
> option ANSI_NULLS is set to OFF, comparisons between nulls, such as
> NULL = NULL, evaluate to TRUE. **Comparisons between NULL and any data
> value evaluate to FALSE**.

Comment: May you please explain why?

Comment: @GiladGreen explained.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that :)

Comment: Your predicate is wrong. It either has to be null or not 201.

Answer (score 1):

Because `null` in SQL means 'unknown'. Can you say that 'something you don't know' is not `201`? No, you can't.

So you have to tell explicitly you want to include null values by checking on `null` equality. In this regard, databases are different from the C# programming language where `null == null`.

This would do:

```
where tb.Column3 == null || tb.Column3 != 201
```

Answer (score 0):

If you compare NULL with anything (even NULL) with logical operators, it will return false. So NULL != 201 is false. You need to use something like this:

```
where tb.Column3 is null or tb.Column3 != 201
```

or you can use isnull statement:

```
where isnull(tb.Column3, 0) != 201
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server has a different NULL-Semantic than C#. In C# when something is != 201, it may be null. However in SQL Server when something is != 201 it may not be null. Therefore you have to tell SQL Server that you want NULL or != 201

```
from tb in _entities.Table1
where tb.Column3 == null || tb.Column3 != 201
```